# SaveFileDialog locking save file location c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I am using the save file dialog to get the location where I want to save my file.

```
private string GetSaveLocationFromUser(string filter)
{
    string location = string.Empty;

    using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        sfd.Filter = filter;
        sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
        sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        sfd.InitialDirectory = GetFolderNameDefault();
        sfd.FileName = GetFileDefaultName();

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            location = sfd.FileName;
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

This works fine in getting the file location, however when I go to actually save my file later on in the code, I am getting an exception saying that the file already exists and therefore cannot save the file.

The below code is using ClosedXML to save an excel document at the chosen location.

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    wb.Worksheets.Add(data, ReportTitle);
    wb.SaveAs(filename);
    isSuccess = true;
}
```

If I alter the filename by 1 character, e.g. test.xlsx --> test1.xlsx it works fine.  It is almost like the save file dialog is putting a lock on that file location when it is selected which means I can't then later save to it?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: check the overload of the .SaveAs` method and see if there is a boolean parameter, which would usually indicate if the file exist to overwrite it.. or write code that checks if the file exist.. then delete if before creating and saving the new file.. simple fix..

Comment: I tried this already with no luck, it is saying that no file exists when I do that check. I also just tried deleting anyway and that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ConflictResolution` parameter of `Workbook.SaveAs` to `xlLocalSessionChanges` so that it always accepts your changes. Something like:

```
wb.SaveAs(filename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: I think the OP isn't using Excel interop but [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml). As far as I can see, the `wb.SaveAs()` method of an `ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook` doesn't have any parameters other than the file name (or the stream) and referring to the [source code](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook.cs) it does overwrite any existing file in any case.